# React shouldComponentUpdate is not be executed while I using immutable.js

Tags: reactjs, immutable.js

I am using immutable.js in React.

```
var BlackBoard = React.createClass({
getInitialState:function() {
    return {
        source : Immutable.fromJS({
            data : ['list1'],
            headerName : 'header-Name',
            footerName : 'footer-Name'})
    }
},
render:function() {
    var rows = [];
    var data = this.state.source.get('data');
    var headerName = this.state.source.get('headerName');
    var footerName = this.state.source.get('footerName');
    for (var i = 0;i < data.size; i ++){
        rows.push(<ListView key = {i} index = {i} name = {data[i]} handleClickIndex = {this.handleClickIndex} />);
    }
    return (<div>
        <Header key = {headerName} headerName = {headerName} />
        {rows}
        <Footer key = {footerName} footerName = {footerName} />
    </div>);
},
handleClickIndex(index){//just update header data in source.
    var source = this.state.source.set('headerName','new Header-Name');
     this.setState({source : this.state.source});
}
});
```

---

```
var HeaderComponent = React.createClass({
shouldComponentUpdate : function (nextProps,nextState) {
    console.log('header component executes shouldComponentUpdate');
    return true;
},
render(){
    return <div className="Header">{this.props.headerName}</div>
}
});
```

---

```
var FooterComponent = React.createClass({
shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps, nextState) {
    console.log('footer component executes shouldComponentUpdate');
    return true;
},
render(){
    return <div className="Footer">{this.props.footerName}</div>
}
});
```

---

when the function 'handleClickIndex' was executed.I update the 'headerName' data with 'new Header-Name' in the 'source'.And execute 'setState' to re-render all children component.    My issue is that the lifecycle function 'shouldComponentUpdate' of the ListView components in the rows and the footer component can be executed but not  in Header component.   I think all children components should executed the function 'shouldComponentUpdate'.My goal is to use immutable data in the function 'shouldComponentUpdate' to avoid re-rendering.Thanks a lot!

Comment: Oh,I use immutable.js in a wrong way.Now I found a [blog](https://blog.risingstack.com/the-react-js-way-flux-architecture-with-immutable-js/) here.This blog tells me how React works with immutable.js in flux.

Comment: mind sharing what part of the blog specifically helped you out?